# AWS - LAMBDA - CLI - update-function-code - not reachable in this region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I try to trigger the update-function-code through the Command line, I'm getting an error "not reachable in this region".

I believe that my current config profile being in eu-west-2 region is conflicting with the function deployment to us-east-1.  Without having to change my profile and/or region, what is the best way to allow my user to access/write to this regions lambda function

```
aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name  arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:function:xxxxxx \ 
    --zip-file fileb://lambda_bundle.zip
```

ERROR:
An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: Functions from 'us-east-1' are not reachable in this region ('eu-west-2')

Answer (score 5):

Usually you would just add [--region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html)  to your command:

```
aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name  arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:function:xxxxxx \ 
    --zip-file fileb://lambda_bundle.zip \
    --region us-east-1
```